# twitter-node detecting connection end

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm using the [twitter-node library](https://github.com/technoweenie/twitter-node) for node.js and it works well, however I'm having some minor difficulty handling disconnects.

When twitter disconnects me (I'm connecting a second time from the same server to force a disconnect so I can make sure I'm handling these sorts of issues) it doesn't produce an error or an end event.I thought the following would handle it:

```
var twitter = new TwitterNode({
  user       : opts.account,
  password   : opts.password,
  track      : opts.hashtags,
  follow     : opts.follow
});

// omitted handlers for receiving tweets/deletes/limit info, but its there
twitter.addListener('error', function(error) {
  console.log('error occoured:'  + error.message);
}).addListener('end', function(resp) {
    sys.puts("wave goodbye... " + resp.statusCode);
}).stream();
```

However, I don't get either the message from 'end' or 'error' when I'm disconnected. Anyone familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having this same issue:

There's no notification from twitter-node because it doesn't handle the https libraries close event - by going into the source and adding:

```
response.on('close', function() { twit.emit('close',this); }
```

The library now emits a close event when the connection is closed by the remote server (twitter) and you can handle it with a listener in your code like this:

```
twitterStreamReader = new TwitterNode({...});
twitterStreamReader.addListener('close', function(resp) {
  sys.puts('The server connection has been closed. You may want to do something about that.');
});
```